# Which article to use and why?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

Which article should I use and why, both seem correct to my senses.

Here I'm talking only about a leg of mine not both.

> 1. a) I have the leg of a footballer.

OR

> 1. b) I have a leg of a footballer.

Here a person only can have a single body.

> 2. a) I have the body of a supermodel.

OR

> 2. b) I have a body of a supermodel.

Comment: Would you tell us what you are intended to convey by those sentences? For instance, without any context, ***I have a/the leg of a footballer*** might mean you actually have the body part at your hands.

Comment: The meaning I intend is (1.a) where I'm talking about a single leg of mine which is too good for an average football player so that's why I'm comparing it to a professional footballer (say, right leg) but if I use "a" there will it be considered as "incorrect',if so then why? I can't extract any major difference.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you should use the *definite article*. It doesn't matter if the object is singular or plural:

- I have the legs of a footballer
- I have the body of a supermodel

The reason these expressions use the definite article is that you are referring to *a specific* body part from *one person*. Even though you are not specifying *which* footballer or model, whoever they may be, they can only have one body or pair of legs.

A similar idiom refers, not to a specific footballer or model (sticking with your examples) but to *any* footballer or model, and as such it uses the indefinite article:

- I have a body *like a supermodel*
- I have legs *like a footballer*

The difference between these two idioms is like the difference between a simile and a metaphor. In the first idiom, you are saying that you actually posess the body or legs of another person, so it is specific and requires the definite article. The second idiom is just likening your body to any particular footballer / model, and so is non-specific.

Comment: I smell what you're steppin'.